# C# RemoveBG API

Tags: c#, background

Please anybody can help me to remove the background of an image, using remove bg API. there given once example. but i can't understand it.
I need to upload image on picturebox and need to get the png in to a picturebox. anybody can give me a compleate example code for this?

remove bg .Net Example is here.

https://www.remove.bg/api

My code is here.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void removebg()
{
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
formData.Headers.Add("X-Api-Key",
"xxxxxxxxkeyxxxxxxxx");
formData.Add(new
StringContent("https://www.remove.bg/example.jpg"), "image_url");
formData.Add(new StringContent("auto"), "size");
var response =
client.PostAsync("https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg",
formData).Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("no-bg.png",
FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

response.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ContinueWith((copyTask) => {
fileStream.Close(); });


pictureBox1.Load("https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg/no-bg.png");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Error");
Console.WriteLine("Error: " +
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
}
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: sure we can help you, show us what you have tried first?

Comment: Thank you. here is the code.

Comment: Code here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fD2K_gwLkYJ6zALSvkKbMMQ6qpusWHrZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: please update (edit) your question here, do not use any external systems

Comment: thanks maytham. already edited my question. now ok?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a file address to save the result here FileStream("no-bg.png",

```
string destFullName = @"C:\Users\FrédéricPoll\MyTemp\PictueBackGround\removebg.png";
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(destFullName , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
```

Then laod it into the pictureBox :

```
pictureBox1.Load(destFullName);
```